# Setting ng-model inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of questions and each question have some options with checkbox. I'm using an `ng-repeat` to list the questions and another `ng-repeat` to list the options. So how should I set the `ng-model` for the answer option checkbox to get all the selected options for all questions.

I tried setting `ng-model` like this `answers[qst.id][ans.id]`, But its returning error `TypeError: Cannot set property '*' of undefined`

```
<div ng-repeat="qst in questions">
    <div>{{qst.question}}</div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="ans in answers">
                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="answers[qst.id][ans.id]">
                </span>
                <span>
                    {{ans.ansOption}}
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the perfect way to do that ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property '*' of undefined is literally the most common error of angular. Could you update the error with the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: I did only this much. Set $scope.questions in the controller and above code in template. And now when I try to check the check box, this error occurs. Is this the actual way to do this ?

Comment: @I'mnidhin include answers sample data

Comment: @I'mnidhin could you add plunkr with proble, reproducible/

Answer (score 0):

Dont know your structure of Answers, but it is probably object (key-value pair), so i binded your checkbox to key  `checked` in answer.

```
<div ng-repeat="qst in questions">
    <div>{{qst.question}}</div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="ans in answers[qst.id]"><span><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ans.checked"></span><span>{{ans.ansOption}}</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all questions will be having the same set of answer options. so $scope.answers is a separate entity. Not related to questions